# Can we have a dynamic update attribute value in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

There is a scenario where we want to update some tabs in an accordion panel based on data selection in the tabs and exclude some tabs from update based on certain selections.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="cc-accordion-panel" 
                              widgetVar="AccorPnl"
                              activeIndex="#{managerBean.accordionTabIndices}"
                              multiple="true"
                              dynamic="false"
                              styleClass="accordion-with-ancors"
                              style="border-bottom:1px solid #A3BCC4;">

               <p:ajax  event="tabChange"
                        update="cc-accordion-panel:datatable1
                                cc-accordion-panel:datatable2
                                cc-accordion-panel:datatable3
                                cc-accordion-panel:datatable4" />
    ...
    ...
  </p:accordionPanel>
```

Can we get the update id list from a backing bean property at run time? Something like ...

```
<p:accordionPanel id="cc-accordion-panel" 
                              widgetVar="#{widgetVarPrefix}AccorPnl"
                              activeIndex="#{managerBean.accordionTabIndices}"
                              multiple="true"
                              dynamic="false"
                              styleClass="bx-accordion-with-ancors"
                              style="border-bottom:1px solid #A3BCC4;">

                <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                        update="#{managerBean.accordionUpdateIds}" 
                        process="#{managerBean.accordionUpdateIds}"/>

        ...
        ...
        ...
  </p:accordionPanel>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Should work just fine. How exactly does it fail for you? Or haven't you even tried it? Why not?

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I added a listener as well which will determine the IDs then it worked.

Comment: In the future try asking a question about a concrete problem instead of a seemingly rhetorical question which can easily be answered by just trying it yourself.